# problem with output numbers in dart with stdin

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, scanf, console-application, stdin

**The output with numbers does not work, I can only write the first number and after that the application closes.**

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print("Escreva o numero de carros vendidos pelo funcionario ");
  int nuyCar = stdin.readByteSync().toInt();

  print("Escreva o salario fixo do funcionario: ");
  double fixSalary = stdin.readByteSync().toDouble();

  print("Escreva o valor arrecadado das vendas do funcionario: ");
  double priceCollected = stdin.readByteSync().toDouble();

  print(nuyCar);
  print(fixSalary);
  print(priceCollected);
}
```

Comment: It "works" for me, but the behavior maybe is not what you intend.  You use `readByteSync`, which reads only a single byte (not an entire line).  If you type `12` and press Enter, then `nuyCar` will be the ASCII value of the character `1` (49), `fixSalary` will be a double of the ASCII value of the character `2` (50.0), and `priceCollected` will be a double of the ASCII value of the linefeed character (10.0).

Answer (score 0):

Well, Dart is one of those languages that heavily relies on null-checks. Read more about it here -> https://dart.dev/null-safety

You should get in habit of checking for those. Also, instead of `readBytes()`, you can use `readLineSync()`.

Your program could be written as such:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {

  int? nuyCar = 0;
  double? fixSalary = 0.0;
  double? priceCollected = 0.0;

  print("Escreva o numero de carros vendidos pelo funcionario ");
  var line = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (line != null) {
    nuyCar = int.parse(line);
  }

  print("Escreva o salario fixo do funcionario: ");
  line = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (line != null) {
    fixSalary = double.parse(line);
  }

  print("Escreva o valor arrecadado das vendas do funcionario: ");
  line = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (line != null) {
    priceCollected = double.parse(line);
  }

  print(nuyCar);
  print(fixSalary);
  print(priceCollected);
}
```